# Post-apocalyptic book involving a protagonist who needs antibiotics, and an underground colony

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I read an excerpt of a book in one of those edited collections that pops up in school libraries, and I've been trying to find the book. It's been years and I've searched every forum, best of list, and edited book index I can find but to no avail. I've read this forum thoroughly too, but it could be a not seeing the forest for the trees situation so I apologise if I'm asking an old question.

I graduated school in 2004, so if I did read it at my school library, it predates that. I do remember it being pre-2000, as I think it was early high school. The edited work I read I think was a 90's publication but it had little in the way of proper credits for its source material to know when that was published. Also, as an early teenager, I didn't think to look at such things then, like I do now.

The information I have is this:

The protagonist lives above ground, after some sort of extinction-level event. There is a colony of survivors below ground. They have hydroponically grown food, water treatment plants, that kind of thing. For some reason the protagonist needs antibiotics, and this is central to the theme. For their parent, I think? They are able to contact this underground colony but I cannot remember the context.

What I do remember is that that one of the people in power in this colony uses an imbalance of power to keep the protagonist returning, by only giving half the course of antibiotics. I cannot remember what the power holder wants from the protagonist, but I do remember something about the water treatment plant needing something from the surface, as it is about to fail and poison the colony. I could be wrong on that but water and poison featured as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read the extract and do you have any sense of when the original book might've been published?

Comment: Thank you, that would have been sensible to add.
My memory is not great so these details may not be accurate.
I graduated school in 2004, so if I did read it at my school library, it predates that.
I do remember it being pre-2000, as I think it was early high school.
The edited work I read I think was a 90's publication but it had little in the way of proper credits for its source material to know when that was published.  Also, as an early teenager, I didn't think to look at such things then, like I do now.

Comment: Some parts of your description sound a bit like Philip K Dick's [The Penultimate Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Penultimate_Truth), but other bits don't. So maybe not.

Comment: Thank you, it's a great start! I imagine I'll be led to many great novels anyway on this journey so any help is going to be appreciated no matter how close to the actual story.